# how to get from a txt document which includes a name and three marks in a csv document. to put every mark in a separate slot

Tags: c, copy, txt

the txt document includes:

```
Mayer 1.3 1.7 4.0
Mueller 2.0 3.0 4.0
Schulze 1.7 5.0 4.0
```

till now i got to copy the names and marks, but each name and his marks are in one slot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *noten, *noten_excel1, *noten_excel2;
    int zeichen;

    printf("\n");

    if ((noten = fopen("C:\\Users\\seidel\\Desktop\\InfoC\\noten.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("lesen fehlgeschlagen\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((noten_excel1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\seidel\\Desktop\\InfoC\\noten_excel1.csv", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("schreiben fehlgeschlagen\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((zeichen = fgetc(noten)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(zeichen, noten_excel1);
    }
    fclose(noten);
    fclose(noten_excel1);
}
```

Comment: "...  are in one slot" hmm.. to me that's pretty unclear. What does it mean?

Comment: In general you could solve this with `fgets()` and apply `strtok` to each line read.

Comment: To me the code looks like a simple file copy... you read and character and write the same character... where do you apply some logic?

Comment: I *think* you're asking how to take the per-line data shown and xform it into a CSV (e.g. stick commas in between cells. You should provide a "This is what I'm trying to get as output" example, as it related to the provided input, in your question, and detail in your code exactly how you've tried to get there.

Comment: I think it could be helpful if you showed how you want the output file to look

Comment: A brutal way would be to simply replace every space with a comma. `if(zeichen == ' ') zeichen = ',';`

Comment: I vote to close because it's unclear what OP is trying to do and what the problem with the code is.

Comment: in the csv document it should look like A1|Mayer|B1|1.3|C1|1.7|D1|4.0| ( those | represent slots.